# In American Gods is the Myths of the gods, something that happened, or something that emerged as a belief?

Tags: american-gods, norse-gods, odin

One of the central themes of American god lore is that Gods, like Wednesday, Mr.Nancy, Chernobog were made out of people's beliefs. and their existence is tied to the devotion of their followers. But where then does, their mythos come from ?

For e.g. Odin, the All father, sacrificed his eye and hung from a tree for 9 days and nights for knowledge. Is that something that is 'part of the narrative'so to speak? or something that could've happened.

Or is it, the gods were born with this settings implanted, via the devotion of their followers, and then they rolled with it?

Comment: I think the answer is a firm yes to both (recursively). People's beliefs make the god, who then has a backstory that matches their belief, even if that backstory makes no logical sense

Comment: See also ["A Dream of a Thousand Cats"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Sandman:_Dream_Country#%22A_Dream_of_a_Thousand_Cats%22) by Neil: reality is shaped in the most literal sense by the dreams, beliefs, and expectations of humans.